# Do I understand this counting problem correctly?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A number plate consists of between $4$ and $6$ symbols which are either letters or digits. How many number plates have exactly 4 symbols? How many have exactly $5$? How many number plates are there altogether?

Does this problem mean that a number plate consists of all letters or all digits but can not be a combination of the letters and digits?

So the answer to first part is $26^4+10^4$, the answer to second part is $26^5+10^5$ and the answer to the last part is $26^4+10^4+26^5+10^5+26^6+10^6$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this problem mean that a number plate consists of all letters or all digits but can not be a combination of the letters and digits?

Regarding this, I would usually assume the former - think of license plate numbers as an example. Thus, I would consider a four-symbol plate to be "$xxxx$" where each particular $x$ can be an English letter or a number.

I don't blame you though, the problem is a bit ambiguous as to that. (As well as with respect to alphabet, capitalization, blahblahblah but let's not overcomplicate matters.) It's basically a matter of whether to use the "exclusive or" (can be letters or numbers but not both) or the "inclusive or" (can be letters, numbers, or a combination of both).

***Generally*** when not stated otherwise and you have no reason to believe otherwise, you should probably go with "inclusive or" (letters, numbers, or a combo of both in this scenario), just owing to the nature of these sorts of problems. That's never a guarantee though, but generally the "inclusive or" case is more often the intent.

In any event, your solutions are consistent with your latter assumption from the quote (the "exclusive or"): if you can only have letters *or* numbers but not both, then your calculations are correct.

Using instead the assumptions you can have any combination of letters or numbers, though, the computations aren't any more complex. You would have $26+10=36$ choices per symbol, so there are $36^4$ and $36^5$ four- and five-symbol plates respectively under those assumptions. And of course, $36^4 + 36^5 + 36^6$ total.

---

Regarding which solution the problem desires, you might have to figure that out on your own. You could ask your teacher, if this is for a class. If this is in a textbook, the answer may be in the back, with the correct answer(s) corresponding to the appropriate assumptions, more likely than not.

If neither gives a proper answer or is available, though, I would hedge on my earlier note and just err on the side of "inclusive or."